# How to read or write smart card

Tags: smartcard, pcsc

Im new with smart card. I have some smart card (ISO 7816-4 support) but don't have the specification and omnikey reader. Im using pcsc sharp. I can transmit only get challenge instruction successfully. I can read the ATR too. One of my card ATR is 3B-DB-94-00-80-31-FE-45-00-31-C0-64-20-27-02-00-00-90-00-45. But cannot transmit any other instruction. The response that is getting by sw1 and sw2 is like "file not found", "Wrong parameter" and so on. 
My question is Is there any common way to read or write on a smart card. 
And Can I read or write to a smart card that vendor specification is not known.

Comment: Which reader you are using

Comment: The pdf of ISO7816-4 is available online at http://www.embedx.com/pdfs/ISO_STD_7816/info_isoiec7816-4%7Bed2.0%7Den.pdf

Comment: Im using Omnikey reader. I have seen iso7816-4 specification and following the instruction but not successful.

Comment: which omnikey reader ? Can you specify the reader no.

Comment: Try to select the MF by APDU "00A40000023F00".

Comment: Can you pleas explain the command like Cls - "00", INS - "A4", P1- "00", P2-"00" ... but what r the rest ?? is it data and lc field ??

Comment: 3F00 is default File ID for MF. 0x02 is the length of data field.You should read ISO 7816-4.

Comment: I run this command response sw1 - 90 sw2- 00 .. that means no further information. what i do next after selecting MF file.

Comment: First, create a file structure and write some data and read it.Refer section 5.3 in ISO 7816-4 for file structure.

Comment: @vikky hi I have read pdf but it does not instruct me what to do and its hazy to. May be im missing somthing. I have search how to create ef files but found nothing. Card vendor replied that its easy to write on card with apdu command. But they does not give any specification. Can you plz give me and example to creating ef file command. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try these Apdu's

Select MF APDU :

> 00 A4 00 00 00

Create EF APDU(Transmit binary file with File ID 0X3F01) :

> 00 E0 00 00  09 62 07 83 02 3F 01 82 01 01

Write Data APDU (data - 0102030405):

> 00 D0 00 00 05

Read 5 byte data:

> 00 B0 00 00 05

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I can select mf file but cannot create ef. Response is 6A 80 thats means Incorrect parameters in the data field. Does file ID deffer form card to card ??

Answer (score -1):

Most of smart cards follows the global platform standard nowadays, even internally it may not be a java card.

So you need know the key to authenticate the card, and use some global platform based tool to access card.

One option tool like:

https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro

There is another javascript based shell that you can use to do some interactive scription:

http://www.openscdp.org/scsh3/

Basically, you need know what kind of data and command you need to modify data, and what type of authentication you need do before execute further operation.

Comment: Actually my requirement is to write some data on smart card and then read that data. Is it possible with this ??

Comment: @Md.Yusuf if you only want write data, for example some EF file, then you need know the exact command and the required authentication to do that. otherwise, no tool can help you directly.